# how to theme images uploaded with multi-value field?

Tags: theming, media

I have a multi-value image field. Now I want to theme it based on the number of the uploaded images.

if there is one image {
//theme here
}
if there is 2 image {
//theme here
}

And so on. I'm trying to do it in field--field_project_image.tpl.php file. I can use

```
foreach($items as $values => $item) {
  print '<div class="myclass">'.render($item) . '</div>';
}
```

but I think i need to use if statement and then be able to style each picture differently.

Comment: while this question seems to be just about php and css and not really drupal specific, a quick `$num=count($items);` will give you the number of items/images, so after that it's all up to you to use it in a css class name or however.  if the actual structure needs to be different based on the number, I'd look into  `switch($num)` instead of a giant `if/else` construct.

Comment: The problem is that when i print $items it prints not the fields but the other things mentioned in the node.tpl.php. How can I print items without foreach?

Comment: `$items` should be an array of the items in the field, and `render($item)` if called like above will create the html needed to display that field.  You can also create them individually, eg `render($items[0])` or `render($items[5])`